# Converts minutes into days, week, months and years

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose I have a number which represents the minutes passed from the start time to now.

I wan to create a function which returns the years, months, week and days corresponding to the minutes I am passing to that function.

Here an example:

```
var minutes = 635052; // 635052 = (24*60)*365 + (24*60)*30*2 + (24*60)*14 + (24*60)*2 + 12;
getDataHR(minutes); // 1 year, 2 months, 2 week, 2 days, 12 minutes

function getDataHR (newMinutes) {
      minutes = newMinutes;
      .......
      return hrData; // 1 year, 2 months, 2 week, 2 days, 12 minutes
}
```

What is the best way to achieve the result?

Comment: Do you use some reference date for 0 minute? It might be needed for calculating the correct month length.

Comment: Yes, the reference for 0 minutes is the current date. So `var minutes = 2;` means 2 minutes from now.

Comment: You will have to be a lot more precise to get a decent answer.  What do you mean by "months, weeks, and days?"  Today is October 18th.  How many months, weeks, and days are there between now and the same time on November 29th (35 days away)?  How many days are there between 11:59PM today and 12:01AM tomorrow?  Zero? One?

Comment: Use the JavaScript native Date object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
var units = {
    "year": 24*60*365,
    "month": 24*60*30,
    "week": 24*60*7,
    "day": 24*60,
    "minute": 1
}

var result = []

for(var name in units) {
  var p =  Math.floor(value/units[name]);
  if(p == 1) result.push(p + " " + name);
  if(p >= 2) result.push(p + " " + name + "s");
  value %= units[name]

}
```

Comment: What... about... hours? :P

Answer (score 8):

Building off of [thg435's response above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813078/142225), I created a function that converts seconds to days, hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
function secondsToString(seconds)
{
   var value = seconds;

   var units = {
       "day": 24*60*60,
       "hour": 60*60,
       "minute": 60,
       "second": 1
   }

   var result = []

   for(var name in units) {
     var p =  Math.floor(value/units[name]);
     if(p == 1) result.push(" " + p + " " + name);
     if(p >= 2) result.push(" " + p + " " + name + "s");
     value %= units[name]
   }

   return result;

}
```

I also added some spaces to the result to give the commas some room.  Output looks like:

```
1 day, 3 hours, 52 minutes, 7 seconds.
```

Answer (score 5):

I did it like this, because I didn't even know there was a modulo operator in javascript:

```
var minutes = 635052; // 635052 = (24*60)*365 + (24*60)*30*2 + (24*60)*14 + (24*60)*2 + 12;
getDataHR(minutes); // 1 year, 2 months, 2 week, 2 days, 12 minutes

function getDataHR (newMinutes) {
    MINS_PER_YEAR = 24 * 365 * 60
    MINS_PER_MONTH = 24 * 30 * 60
    MINS_PER_WEEK = 24 * 7 * 60
    MINS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60
    minutes = newMinutes;
    years = Math.floor(minutes / MINS_PER_YEAR)
    minutes = minutes - years * MINS_PER_YEAR
    months = Math.floor(minutes / MINS_PER_MONTH)
    minutes = minutes - months * MINS_PER_MONTH
    weeks = Math.floor(minutes / MINS_PER_WEEK)
    minutes = minutes - weeks * MINS_PER_WEEK
    days = Math.floor(minutes / MINS_PER_DAY)
    minutes = minutes - days * MINS_PER_DAY
    return years + " year(s) " + months + " month(s) " + weeks + " week(s) " + days + " day(s) " + minutes + " minute(s)"
    //return hrData; // 1 year, 2 months, 2 week, 2 days, 12 minutes
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use division and modulus:

```
function getDataHR (newMinutes) {
    var hrData = "";

    var years = minutes / YEAR_IN_MINUTES; // int division = no remainder
    hrData += years + "years";
    minutes = minutes % YEAR_IN_MINUTES;

    // ... continue for months, weeks, days, hours, etc. in that order

    return hrData; // 1 year, 2 months, 2 week, 2 days, 12 minutes
}
```

Comment: Why is it int division and not float?

Comment: In javascript it might make it into a float.  So you can just surround it with `Math.floor(...)` to round it down.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have implemented some code that would some work for someone

```
const MINS_PER_YEAR = 24 * 365 * 60,
  MINS_PER_MONTH = 24 * 30 * 60,
  MINS_PER_WEEK = 24 * 7 * 60,
  MINS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60;

const hours = (minutes) => {
  const hour = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  const remainingMinutes = minutes - hour * 60;
  return `${hour} hours ${remainingMinutes} minutes`;
};

const days = (minutes) => {
  const days = Math.floor(minutes / (24 * 60));
  const remainingMinutes = minutes - days * 24 * 60;
  const hour = hours(remainingMinutes);

  return `${days} days ${hour}`;
};

const weeks = (minutes) => {
  const weeks = Math.floor(minutes / (24 * 7 * 60));
  const remainingMinutes = minutes - weeks * (24 * 7 * 60);
  if (remainingMinutes <= MINS_PER_DAY) return `${weeks} weeks ${hours(remainingMinutes)}`;
  else return `${weeks} weeks ${days(remainingMinutes)}`;
};

const months = (minutes) => {
  const months = Math.floor(minutes / MINS_PER_MONTH);
  const remainingMinutes = minutes - months * MINS_PER_MONTH;
  if (remainingMinutes <= 60) return `${months} months ${hours(remainingMinutes)}`;
  else if (remainingMinutes <= MINS_PER_DAY) return `${months} months ${days(remainingMinutes)}`;
  else return `${months} months ${weeks(remainingMinutes)}`;
};

export const convertMinutes = (minutes) => {
  if (minutes <= 60) return `${minutes} minutes`;
  else if (minutes <= MINS_PER_DAY) return hours(minutes);
  else if (minutes <= MINS_PER_WEEK) return days(minutes);
  else if (minutes <= MINS_PER_MONTH) return weeks(minutes);
  else return months(minutes);
};
```