# Show TimeSpan on Value Axis in Kendo Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I want to show TimeSpan values on my Value axis. Chart is working fine for numeric but if I change to TimeSpan nothing is showing. I checked the data and it's ok. If TimeSpan is not supported is there a way to format minutes in int values to be shown as Time (ie ,,6h 34 min")

Here is my chart:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MachineWorkTimeChartViewModel>()
    .Name("chartMachineWorkTime")
     .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("MachineWorkTimeChart_Read", "Charts")
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
        .Background("transparent")
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Bar(e => e.WorkTimeSpan).Name("Time of work");
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Name("label-axis")
         .Categories(e => e.MachineName)
          .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
    )
```

)

and here is my ViewModel:

```
    public class MachineWorkTimeChartViewModel
{
    public int WorkMinutes { get; set; }

    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan WorkTimeSpan => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(WorkMinutes);
}
```

Comment: You can use a template and the moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)  library to go from minutes to timespan durations e.g.: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/vKvRAz

Comment: @ezanker I'd mark your post as answer if you'd post it as one. Template was the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answer ezanker and modified js function from jgritty [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812742/converts-minutes-into-days-week-months-and-years) 
I got it to work (I didn't want to use an external js library).

Here is full example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MachineWorkTimeChartViewModel>()
    .Name("chartMachineWorkTime")
     .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("MachineWorkTimeChart_Read", "Charts")
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
        .Background("transparent")
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Bar(e => e.WorkMinutes).Name("Time of work");
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Name("series-axis")
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
    )
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Name("label-axis")
         .Categories(e => e.MachineName)
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric()
            .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0} min.")
             .Template("#= getTimeSpanFromMinutes(value) #"))
            // Move the label-axis all the way down the value axis
            .AxisCrossingValue(0, int.MinValue)
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("{0}%")
        .Template("#= getTimeSpanFromMinutes(value) #")
    ))


<script>

function getTimeSpanFromMinutes(newMinutes) {
    var minsPerYear = 24 * 365 * 60;
    var minsPerMonth = 24 * 30 * 60;
    var minsPerWeek = 24 * 7 * 60;
    var minsPerDay = 24 * 60;
    var minsPerHour = 60;
    var minutes = newMinutes;
    var years = Math.floor(minutes / minsPerYear);
    minutes = minutes - years * minsPerYear;
    var months = Math.floor(minutes / minsPerMonth);
    minutes = minutes - months * minsPerMonth;
    var weeks = Math.floor(minutes / minsPerWeek);
    minutes = minutes - weeks * minsPerWeek;
    var days = Math.floor(minutes / minsPerDay);
    minutes = minutes - days * minsPerDay;
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / minsPerHour);
    minutes = minutes - hours * minsPerHour;

    var timeSpan = "";

    if (years > 0)
        timeSpan += years + " years ";
    if (months > 0)
        timeSpan += months + " months ";
    if (weeks > 0)
        timeSpan += weeks + " weeks ";
    if (days > 0)
        timeSpan += weeks + " days ";
    if (hours > 0)
        timeSpan += hours + " hours ";
    if (minutes > 0)
        timeSpan += minutes + " min. ";

    return timeSpan;
}</script>
```